# PhantomJS: Blank pages when scraping multiple URLs

Tags: phantomjs

I have written a PhantomJs script to scrape multiple URLs by chaining calls to page.open() recursively. (Code snippet below.) This works for upto 3 or 4 URLs, however with a larger number of URLs I just get blank pages. By blank, I mean that document.URL contains "about: blank", and a screenshot just shows a blank white background. I have also noticed that memory usage of phantomJs keeps increasing as it continues to process a large number of URLs. Is there anything specific I need to to do deallocate any memory used to render previous pages?

Have other people seen this issue? Is it possible to scale PhantomJs to scrape a larger number of URLs (say 100)?

Thanks
Rohit

Recursive code snippet to scrape multiple URLs:

```
srcProducts = [{'url':'http://...' }, { 'url': 'http://...' },...];
destProducts = [];
gRetries = 0;
process();

function process() {
  if (srcProducts.length == 0) {
    // Output to file
    phantom.exit();
  } else {
     product = srcProducts.pop();

     page = require('webpage').create();
     page.open(product['url'], onOpen);
  }
}

function onOpen(status) {
  // check status
  // scrape info into product

  destProducts.push(product);
  process();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Someone was kind enough to answer this question on google groups. The solution is to call page.release() after you are done using a page object.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/phantomjs/lquzLFvZtrA

Comment: Was that *other thread* on Stack Overflow? Or another site?  Can you provide more detail so this question is useful to future visitors?

Answer (score 0):

page.release() has been deprecated in the current version of PhantomJS (v1.9).

You should now use page.close() instead to free the page from memory.

http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/release.html
http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/close.html